# Duplicate records created in IActionResult (Entity Framework Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have no idea why the following code sometimes create duplicate records with different record ID. I suspect the user has post multiple times. If so, how should I change the code to prevent this?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Add(LeaveHandleViewModel LeaveVM)
{
        //Check if record exists
        if (_context.InOutRecords.Where(x => x.User == User.Identity.Name 
                    && x.StartForm == LeaveVM.TodayDate).Count() > 0)
        {
            //Modify record
            var LeaveRecord = _context.InOutRecords.Where(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name 
                                && x.StartForm == LeaveVM.TodayDate).FirstOrDefault();

            LeaveRecord.Remarks = LeaveVM.TodayRemarks;

            var entry = _context.Entry(LeaveRecord);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            //create new record
            Leave LeaveRecord = new Leave();
            LeaveRecord.Remarks = LeaveVM.TodayRemarks;
            LeaveRecord.StartForm = LeaveVM.TodayDate;
            LeaveRecord.User = User.Identity.Name;
            LeaveRecord.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

            _context.InOutRecords.Add(LeaveRecord);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the problem is not because of date comparison `x.StartForm == LeaveVM.TodayDate`  or because of some special characters that are in username.

Oh and try code below and let me know if something changed.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Add(LeaveHandleViewModel LeaveVM)
{
    var inOutRecord =  _context.InOutRecords.FirstOrDefault(x => x.User == User.Identity.Name
                    && x.StartForm == LeaveVM.TodayDate);

    if(inOutRecord != null)
    {
            //Edit already existing record
            inOutRecord.Remarks = LeaveVM.TodayRemarks;          
            _context.InOutRecords.Update(inoutRecord);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction(nameOf(Index));
    }else
    {
            //Create new one
            Leave LeaveRecord = new Leave();
            LeaveRecord.Remarks = LeaveVM.TodayRemarks;
            LeaveRecord.StartForm = LeaveVM.TodayDate;
            LeaveRecord.User = User.Identity.Name;
            LeaveRecord.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

            _context.InOutRecords.Add(LeaveRecord);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction(nameOf(Index));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have checked the date and username in the database, it should be fine. I think your code does the same things as mine, but I have learn something from it. I should give more information on the duplicate record. The duplicate record timestamp are so close (under 1 sec). I think if the user clicked the button and it go through the action result logic, this should only happen: a) logic fail b) client send/resend multiple request so fast c) EFCore fail (SaveChanges)